# Image not displaying with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to display an image on my main window, the code seems to work but no image displays. The main code:

```
class MainMenu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Password Manager")

        self.main_menu_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.main_menu_frame.pack()

        script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        image_path = os.path.join(script_path, "PyLock.png")

        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.main_menu_frame, width=200, height=200)
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

        pylock_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="PyLock.png")
        canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=pylock_img)  # Adjusted position

        self.register_button = tk.Button(self.main_menu_frame, text="Register a New User", command=self.show_registration_frame)
        self.register_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.login_button = tk.Button(self.main_menu_frame, text="Log In", command=self.login_button_click)
        self.login_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.exit_button = tk.Button(self.main_menu_frame, text="Exit", command=self.exit_button_click)
        self.exit_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.registration_frame = RegistrationWindow(self.master, self.show_main_menu_frame)

    def show_registration_frame(self):
        self.main_menu_frame.pack_forget()  # Hide the main menu frame
        self.registration_frame.show_frame()  # Show the registration frame

    def login_button_click(self):
        # Placeholder for login logic
        print("Login button clicked")

    def exit_button_click(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def show_main_menu_frame(self):
        self.registration_frame.hide_frame()  # Hide the registration frame
        self.main_menu_frame.pack()  # Show the main menu frame
```

Now, I tested with a smaller amount of code, and the image displayed, yet it does not with the above code. The test code was:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

class MainMenu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Password Manager")

        print(os.getcwd())
        self.main_menu_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.main_menu_frame.pack()

        script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        image_path = os.path.join(script_path, "PyLock.png")

        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.main_menu_frame, width=200, height=200)
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

        pylock_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="PyLock.png")
        canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=pylock_img)  # Adjusted position

        root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainMenu(root)
```

Let it be known that I have tried with my image in the same folder as my .pys and outside the folder, when in the folder "permission denied" (I have changed permissions etc, nothing) and when outside the folder, the code works, but no image displays. There was no issue with the test code, the .py and the .png were both in the same folder there.

***EDIT***

I have tried a new approach:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(self.main_menu_frame, width=200, height=200)
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

        image_path = "PyLock.png"
        pil_image = Image.open(image_path)

        pylock_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
        canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=pylock_img)
```

Still the same results. Image inside the folder, can't be found. Image outside, code runs but no display. [When the code runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn2UC.png)

Comment: The image in first one is garbage collected. Use instance variable `self.pylock_img` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by this? How can it be fixed?

Comment: self.pylock_img has worked, totally overlooked that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all what I noticed in your code is that the line `image_path = os.path.join(script_path, "PyLock.png")` that you imported is not being accessed in other words its existence is not important as its not playing any role in the code. Second of all, yes you are right the second code you provided is working but not the first one and the third thing is that with tkinter I would highly recommend to make use of a library called **[Pillow](https://python-pillow.org)** which is a great library for importing pictures in tkinter.

Till then I am trying to find the source causing this issue.

**[EDIT]**

This working just fine for me:

```
class MainMenu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Password Manager")

        self.main_menu_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.main_menu_frame.pack()

        script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.main_menu_frame, width=200, height=200)
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

        pylock_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="PyLock.png")
        canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=pylock_img)  # Adjusted position

        self.register_button = tk.Button(self.main_menu_frame, text="Register a New User", command=self.show_registration_frame)
        self.register_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.login_button = tk.Button(self.main_menu_frame, text="Log In", command=self.login_button_click)
        self.login_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.exit_button = tk.Button(self.main_menu_frame, text="Exit", command=self.exit_button_click)
        self.exit_button.grid(row=3, column=1)
        
        root.mainloop()

    def show_registration_frame(self):
        self.main_menu_frame.pack_forget()  # Hide the main menu frame
        self.registration_frame.show_frame()  # Show the registration frame

    def login_button_click(self):
        # Placeholder for login logic
        print("Login button clicked")

    def exit_button_click(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def show_main_menu_frame(self):
        self.registration_frame.hide_frame()  # Hide the registration frame
        self.main_menu_frame.pack()  # Show the main menu frame
```

Comment: from a comment above

self.pylock_img has fixed the error. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well as per the given statement I am getting an image a Register a new user, login and an exit button below the image.